# How to create panes that's won't be destroyed when I quit the command that it's running inside?

Tags: shell, command, tmux, pane

I would like to create panes in `tmux` like so :

```
$ tmux new-session -d -s mysession "while true; do sleep 1; ls; done" 
$ tmux split-window -h "while true; do sleep 1; ls -l; done"
```

Running it this way, when I cancel the command that is running in the pane (window) I close it immediately. How to avoid this behaviour ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `remain-on-exit` window option to mark the window (and any panes it contains) to remain after the command it runs exits.

```
tmux new-session -d -s mysession "while true; do sleep 1; ls; done"
tmux set-option -t mysession:0 remain-on-exit
```

When you kill the command, the window will remain, and [the pane] will be labeled "Pane is dead". To restart the same command, issue `respawn-window`. To start a new command in the window (say, an interactive `bash` session), issue `respawn-window bash`.

`respawn-window` (and `respawn-pane`, which I forgot about but can be use to target an individual pane within a window) also take a `-k` option, which can be used to kill whatever is running in a window and either restart the command or start a new command. You could add something to your `.tmux.conf` like

```
bind-key C-c respawn-pane -k bash
```

Then, in *any* active pane, you can type  Control-C to kill whatever is running in the pane and replace it with an interactive shell (`remain-on-exit` would not be necessary in this case, as you are immediately replacing the old command with a new one).

Comment: This method works but it's a little bit annoying to run `respawn-window` after killing the command.

Comment: Your question did not specify any behavior required beyond keeping the window open after the command exited.

Comment: This works like a charm, thanks a lot. But there is another problem ( that I will live aside for now) with turning off commands like e.g. `top` or `less` with for instance button `q`.

Comment: If you quit the command in a pane without killing the pane itself, you'll still need to set the `remain-on-exit` option. The key binding will still work in such a dead pane (`-k` just kills the current command if necessary). There is a `set-remain-on-exit` option for the *session*, which automatically sets `remain-on-exit` for all new windows/panes.